# hard tsql problem - how many row values are in a sequential order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

lets say I have a table with

```
date,personid
1/1/2001 1
1/2/2001 3
1/3/2001 2
1/4/2001 2
1/5/2001 5
1/6/2001 5
1/7/2001 6
```

and I'm going to either update 1/2/2001 or 1/5/2001 with personid 2 but before I can update I have to make sure it passes a rule that says you can't have a person three days in a row.
how can i solve this in a mssql stored procedure?

update: It also need to solve this layout as well where I'd update 1/5/2001

```
date,personid
1/1/2001 1
1/2/2001 3
1/3/2001 2
1/4/2001 2
1/5/2001 1
1/6/2001 2
1/7/2001 2
1/8/2001 5
1/9/2001 5
1/10/2001 6
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you looking for help with T-SQL part or how to write a stored procedure? I'm going to assume the former until you indicate otherwise.

Comment: This is not clear to me. Is only the personid known in advance and you're trying to find a date where you can slot them, or is a list of possible dates known in advance and you need to know which one can accept that personid, or are you just looking for all the possible personids you can change each date to (singly) without violating the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed that `date` is unique let me know if that is not the case!

```
DECLARE @basedata TABLE ([date] UNIQUE DATE,personid INT)
INSERT INTO @basedata
SELECT GETDATE()+1, 2 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+2, 3 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+3, 2 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+4, 2 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+5, 5 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+6, 5 union all
SELECT GETDATE()+7, 6


DECLARE @date date = GETDATE()+5
DECLARE @personid int = 2


;WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP 2 [date],personid   
FROM @basedata 
WHERE [date] < @date
ORDER BY [date] DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT @date, @personid 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 2 [date],personid   
FROM @basedata
WHERE [date] > @date
ORDER BY [date]   
),T2 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp
FROM T
)
SELECT COUNT(*) /*Will return a result if that date/personid 
                  would cause a sequence of 3*/
FROM T2 
GROUP BY personid,Grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
```

Comment: The first line of my answer says I'm assuming `date` is unique. This is not the case then? In which case how are you handling ties?

Comment: hi martin- how would I get the above example to work in the case of only checking for one instead of three in a row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Every row in the table will be a sequence of at least one in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @TargetDate = '1/2/2001'

SELECT @ForwardCount = COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ([date] BETWEEN @TargetDate AND DATEADD(dd, 2, @TargetDate)) WHERE PersonID = @PersonID

SELECT @BackwardCount = COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ([date] BETWEEN @TargetDate AND DATEADD(dd, -2, @TargetDate)) WHERE PersonID = @PersonID

SELECT @BracketCount = COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ([date] BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @TargetDate) AND DATEADD(dd, 1, @TargetDate)) WHERE PersonID = @PersonID

IF (@ForwardCount < 2) AND (@BackwardCount < 2) AND (@BracketCount < 2)
BEGIN
-- Do your update here
END
```

Comment: +1 for this clean easy-to-use answer.
Note that it's missing the constraint about @personid: each `SELECT` should end with `WHERE ... AND personid=@personid`.

Comment: @krubo - This answer might appear more simple but it doesn't work and your proposed fix wouldn't make it work either! (You would just end up excluding other `personid` s so might incorrectly deduce that there was 3 in a row in error)

Comment: @Martin: Please explain your comment.  How does this solution not work?

Comment: @Boo - Probably easier if you edit in your fix then I'll give you some example data that it doesn't work for.

Comment: On example is that it doesn't work for the data in my answer. See http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/99533/ (You will need to choose "Results to Text" to see the result of the second select)

Comment: I get it.  Thanks for the correction.  Should I delete my answer or is the discussion useful?

Answer (score 0):

There is a third case not listed, it is the between date case.  I included it in the solution below.

The output is

```
PersonId    TrackDate  UnallowedBefore UnallowedAfter
----------- ---------- --------------- --------------
2           01/04/2001 01/02/2001      01/05/2001
5           01/06/2001 01/04/2001      01/07/2001
6           01/08/2001 01/08/2001      01/08/2001

USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('PersonDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE PersonDates
CREATE TABLE PersonDates
(
  PersonId  int      NOT NULL,
  TrackDate datetime NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PersonDates
(
  TrackDate, 
  PersonId
)
SELECT '1/1/2001', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/2/2001', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/3/2001', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/4/2001', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/5/2001', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/6/2001', 5
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/7/2001', 6
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/8/2001', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/9/2001', 6

SELECT
  P.PersonId,
  TrackDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day,  1, P.TrackDate), 101),
  T.UnallowedBefore,
  T.UnallowedAfter
FROM
  PersonDates P

  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 
      UnallowedAfter  = CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, P.TrackDate, TrackDate) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day,  1, TrackDate), 101)
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -1, TrackDate), 101)
      END,
      UnallowedBefore = CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, P.TrackDate, TrackDate) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -2, TrackDate), 101)
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -1, TrackDate), 101)
      END
    FROM 
      PersonDates 
    WHERE 
      PersonId = P.PersonId
      AND
      DATEDIFF(day, P.TrackDate, TrackDate) IN (1,2)
  ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my parametrised solution:

```
WITH nearby AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    personid = CASE date WHEN @date THEN @personid ELSE personid END
  FROM atable
  WHERE date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -@MaxInARow, @date)
                 AND DATEADD(day,  @MaxInARow, @date)
),
nearbyGroups AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    Grp = DATEDIFF(day, 0, date) -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY date)
  FROM nearby
)
UPDATE atable
SET personid = @personid
WHERE date = @date
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Grp 
    FROM nearbyGroups
    GROUP BY Grp
    HAVING COUNT(*) > @MaxInARow
  )
```

`@date` represents the date for which the `personid` column should be updated. `@personid` is the new value to be stored. `@MaxInARow` is the maximum number of days in a row for which the same `personid` is allowed to be stored.